# NSMutableArrays store only 2 objects

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, nsmutablearray, nsuserdefaults

I have a weird problem - my mutable array stores only 2 objects - its count is 1,2,2,2 and doesn't change. My only observation is that it always replaces old values f.x. I have: value1 - 2, value2 - 4 and I add next object f.x. 66 and my array look like this: value1 - 4, value2 - 66.
Here is some code:

```
func appendArrays(product: NSString, bPrice: NSString, sPrice: NSString) {
    defaults.synchronize()
    if prodArr.count == 0 {
        prodArr = NSMutableArray(array: [defaults.valueForKey(keys.keyProduct)!])
        bpArr   = NSMutableArray(array: [defaults.valueForKey(keys.keyBPrice)!])
        spArr   = NSMutableArray(array: [defaults.valueForKey(keys.keySPrice)!])
    }

    prodArr.addObject(product)
    bpArr.addObject(bPrice)
    spArr.addObject(sPrice)

    defaults.setObject(prodArr, forKey: keys.keyProduct)
    defaults.setObject(bpArr, forKey: keys.keyBPrice)
    defaults.setObject(spArr, forKey: keys.keySPrice)

    defaults.synchronize()
    NSLog("%i",[defaults.valueForKey(keys.keyBPrice)!].count)
}
```

Comment: I see tons of issues with the way you wrote the code above. Let me know if you need some advices refactoring and make it more typesafe and concise.

Comment: I changed a lot and I think it is quite concise now but I have other problem - how to convert NSArray objectAtIndex to NSString?

Comment: Which line of code is that?

Comment: Why don't you use Swift Types? Why NSString and NSMutableArray?

Comment: To be honest, I don't know why. Maybe I used to from obj-c (it's my first day with swift).
Should I change everything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course you can have not more than two objects because your `spArr` is declared locally and it means that you create a new `spArr` object each time you call `appendArrays`. You need to create it `var spArr: NSMutableArray   = NSMutableArray()` outside the function and instead of doing:

```
spArr   = NSMutableArray(array: [defaults.valueForKey(keys.keySPrice)!])
```

do

```
spArr.addObject([defaults.valueForKey(keys.keySPrice)!])
```

Comment: Thanks! It was so foolish mistake

Comment: Sorry, thought I cannot without 15 reputation

Comment: Why this user defaults doesn't save whole array but just last object?

Comment: because you actually never save the spArr array. you literally save the last object and that's it

Comment: How should I save it? Sorry it's my first day with Swift (I think that in obj-c I haven't to do it)

Comment: Just like you save any other object defaults.setObject(spArr, forKey: "anyKeyYouLike")

Comment: No, you don't. You do save prodArr but not spArr

Comment: What do You mean? I have this lines 'defaults.setObject(spArr, forKey: "anyKeyYouLike")'

Comment: Something may have loaded wrong, maybe try refreshing?

Comment: I have tried several times. there's no such line. however it's not important. if you include this line into your code it MUST work

Answer (score 0):

This is occurring because you're declaring the arrays inside the scope of the function, thus they get destroyed each time you call the method.

Instead declare them at the top of your swift file, just after the Class name, so that they are properties.